# SortableJS - Prevent list item from being moved to another list

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists and using SortableJS (https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) i would like to set some restrictions on the move procedure, but I can't get it to work.

My preferred solution is that a specific item in the list on the left hand side can be moved within that list, but not moved to the list on the right hand side.

As an alternative solution, it would be sufficient if the list on the left hand side is not allowed to be empty, that there always have to be at least one list item in that list.

I have searched SO as well as the rest of the web, but I can't find any similar questions. Do you have some tips I can look into?

Answer (score 1):

So I was facing a similar issue and then made it work using the onMove lifecycle hook in the SortableJS API. In case it helps anyone else.

Say you have 2 lists, listA and listB, and you would like to prevent listA items from being moved to listB, whilst still being sortable within listA.

**Steps:**

1. Attach a distinct class name to the list items, e.g.
   class="itemInA", and "itemInB" for the items in A and B respectively
2. Define a onMove callback function in the initialization of list A which checks the class name to see if the item being moved is being placed beside an item in the unwanted list

```
sortableA = new Sortable(listA, {
    ...
    onMove: function(event) {
       return event.related.className != 'itemInB' // event.related is the key
    }
}
```

**Limitation:** This only works assuming you always have at least 1 item in listB.

**Manual Reference:**

```
// Event when you move an item in the list or between lists
    onMove: function (/**Event*/evt, /**Event*/originalEvent) {
        // Example: https://jsbin.com/nawahef/edit?js,output
        evt.dragged; // dragged HTMLElement
        evt.draggedRect; // DOMRect {left, top, right, bottom}
        evt.related; // HTMLElement on which have guided
        evt.relatedRect; // DOMRect
        evt.willInsertAfter; // Boolean that is true if Sortable will insert drag element after target by default
        originalEvent.clientY; // mouse position
        // return false; — for cancel
        // return -1; — insert before target
        // return 1; — insert after target
        // return true; — keep default insertion point based on the direction
        // return void; — keep default insertion point based on the direction
    },
```

Source: https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable